# pandas pivot to transform DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot

I'm Just trying to play will `pivot` to transform the data Frame in a way i desired which pivot does but here its not working.

Any expert insight please.

### DataFrame:

```
>>> df1
     id   item value
0  2225  prize   1.5
1  2225   unit    kg
2  2225  prize   2.4
3  8187   unit    lt
4  1401  stock    10
5  1401  prize   4.3
```

While running `pivot` i see the below error..

```
>>> df1.pivot('id', 'item')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4359, in pivot
    return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)
  File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py", line 381, in pivot
    return indexed.unstack(columns)
  File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4546, in unstack
    return unstack(self, level, fill_value)
  File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py", line 469, in unstack
    return _unstack_frame(obj, level, fill_value=fill_value)
  File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py", line 488, in _unstack_frame
    fill_value=fill_value)
  File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py", line 116, in __init__
    self._make_selectors()
  File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py", line 154, in _make_selectors
    raise ValueError('Index contains duplicate entries, '
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Even `pivot_table` producing errors..

```
>>> df1.pivot_table(columns='item', values='value')
```

I tried to [github link reference](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8436) but didn't get it.

Desired should be like:

```
      Value

item  prize  stock  unit
    id

2225  1.5  10  2.4  lt
```

Comment: where is oyur stock value for 2225 coming from?

Comment: id `2225` has 2 `prize` , the expected output ignores 1 , why is that? aso what @PV8 said.

Comment: There is question - how aggregate numeric, how aggregate non numeric?

Comment: @anky_91, i didn't get the hold what you asked.

Comment: I meant the expected output doesnot seem correct, the prize if summed up should be `4.30` , you are just taking the first `prize` value for 1 id `2225` for example

Comment: that's just an example way which is to be desired, i agree on the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should try the following:

```
pd.pivot_table(df1, values='value', index=['id'], columns=['item'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

And as mentioned below by jezrael, aggfunc can be mean for numeric values and for strings can be join.

Comment: Let me know if you still face issues.

Comment: ya, working, but sum of strings is join with no space - like `aa, bb` to `aabb`, so be careful

Answer (score 2):

Problem of data is there are duplicates and also mixed numeric with strings in column `value`.

General solution - if need for numeric values `mean` and for duplicates strings `join`:

```
def f(x):
    y = pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')
    if y.isna().all():
        return ', '.join(x)
    else:
        return  y.mean()

df = df1.pivot_table(index='id',columns='item', values='value', aggfunc=f)
print (df)
item prize stock unit
id                   
1401   4.3    10  NaN
2225  1.95   NaN   kg
8187   NaN   NaN   lt
```

Another idea is aggregate numeric and non numeric separate and then `concat` together:

```
df1['value1'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['value'], errors='coerce')

df2 = df1.pivot_table(index='id',columns='item', values='value1', aggfunc='mean')

df3 = df1[df1['value1'].isna()]
            .pivot_table(index='id',columns='item', values='value', aggfunc=','.join)

df = pd.concat([df2, df3], axis=1)
print (df)

item  prize  stock unit
id                     
1401   4.30   10.0  NaN
2225   1.95    NaN   kg
8187    NaN    NaN   lt
```

Comment: Thanks for the adding a detailed answer @Jezrael, appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the pivot doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

```
Raises
------
ValueError:
    When there are any `index`, `columns` combinations with multiple
    values. `DataFrame.pivot_table` when you need to aggregate.
```

In your case, `id=2225` has 2 `prize` entries, which is not handled by `pivot`. You could aggregate first and then pivot:

```py
df1.groupby(['id', 'item']).sum().reset_index().pivot('id', 'item', 'value')

+------+-------+-------+------+
| item | prize | stock | unit |
+------+-------+-------+------+
| id   |       |       |      |
| 1401 | 4.3   | 10    | NaN  |
| 2225 | 3.9   | NaN   | kg   |
| 8187 | NaN   | NaN   | lt   |
+------+-------+-------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Sebastien for the  answer and details, appreciate your help.

Comment: You're welcome @pygo, though I think @ DevendraSwami 's solution with `pivot_table` and `aggfunc` might be more elegant than mine.

Comment: Okay, @Sebastien .. thanks for the thought , i'll accept that.

Answer (score -1):

Pandas is complaining about the fact that you have the entry `(2225, prize)` twice at indices 0 and 2.  This is a database problem rather than a `pandas` misbehaviour.

Fixing this duplicate entry removes the error:

```py
# the original database
>>> df 
     id   item value                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
0  2225  prize   1.5                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
1  2225   unit    kg                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
2  2225  prize   2.4                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
3  8187   unit    lt                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
4  1401  stock    10                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
5  1401  prize   4.3  

# removing the duplicate error by changing index 2
>>> df.loc[2, 'id'] = 8187
>>> df
     id   item value
0  2225  prize   1.5
1  2225   unit    kg
2  8187  prize   2.4
3  8187   unit    lt
4  1401  stock    10
5  1401  prize   4.3

# pivot now works properly
>>> df.pivot('id', 'item')
     value
item prize stock unit
id
1401   4.3    10  NaN
2225   1.5   NaN   kg
8187   2.4   NaN   lt
```

Comment: Thanks @Gregorie for attempting an answer.